# when I use PIL to paste a crop to another image it raises ValueError

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

i am about to paste a little part of 2.jpg to 1.jpg

```
from PIL import Image
body = Image.open("1.jpg")
head = Image.open("2.jpg")
headbox = (0,0,30,30)

head.crop(headbox).save("head.jpg")
body.paste("head.jpg", (0,0)).save("out.jpg")
```

then it throw an error

```
  ****************************************, line 8, in <module>
    body.paste("head.jpg", (0,0)).save("out.jpg")
  File "C:\Users\liton\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1401, in paste
    "cannot determine region size; use 4-item box"
ValueError: cannot determine region size; use 4-item box
```

I use pycharm and python 3.7 and I don't see any syntax error. so what's the matter with the code

Answer (score 12):

You should pass an image object to 'body.paste', however, you were just passing a string (image name). So first you need use open your image with 'Image.open' and then pass it to 'body.paste'. Also, 'body.paste' does not return any value so you cannot use the 'save' method directly. The following code will solve your issue:

```
from PIL import Image
body = Image.open("1.jpg")
head = Image.open("2.jpg")
headbox = (0,0,30,30)

head.crop(headbox).save("head.jpg")
head_crop = Image.open("./head.jpg")
body.paste(head_crop, (0,0))
body.save("out.jpg")
```

Comment: thanks for your consideration, my problem has been solved. actually there are two misktake I have made. 1, a image object should be passed to paste function not a string; 2, the paste function will not return value so it cannot use save method directly.

Comment: @Ridoukei Exactly!